# Limit of function aproximated by some other functions

Tags: calculus

Problem
1.$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x^4+1)}{\log(x^6+1)}$

2.$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n+\sin n}$

1. Its easy with l'Hopital's rule but i was wandering is this correct to say.
   since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x^4+1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x^4)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x^6+1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x^6)$ it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x^4+1)}{log(x^6+1)}$=
   $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(x^4)}{\log(x^6)}=\frac{4}{6}$.
2. i thought same for second problem:$  \sqrt[n]{n-1}<\sqrt[n]{n+\sin n}<\sqrt[n]{n+1}$. Since i know that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ can i just say like above $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ and $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n-1}=1$ so by squezze theorem result is $1$.

Comment: Your answers are correct but the arguements are not correct.

Comment: Well you need to edit by example $sinn$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one indeed we don't need l'Hopital, the correct argument should be

$$\frac{\log(x^4+1)}{\log(x^6+1)}=\frac{\log x^4+\log(1+1/x^4)}{\log x^6+\log(1+1/x^6)}=\frac{4\log x+\log(1+1/x^4)}{6\log x+\log(1+1/x^6)}=$$

$$=\frac{4+\frac{\log(1+1/x^4)}{\log x}}{6+\frac{\log(1+1/x^6)}{\log x}} \to \frac{4+0}{6+0}= \frac23$$

To prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$ let consider

$$\sqrt[n]{n+1}=e^{\frac{\log (n+1)}{n}} \to e^0=1$$

indeed

$$\frac{\log (n+1)}{n}=\frac{\log (n+1)}{n+1} \frac{n+1}{n}\to 0\cdot 1=0$$

Comment: Thank you can u tell me how did u conclude this $\frac{\log(1+1/x^6)}{\log x} \to 0$.

Comment: We have $1/x^6 \to 0$ then $\log(1+1/x^6) \to \log 1=0$ and of course $\frac{\log(1+1/x^6)}{\log x} \to 0$.

Comment: ye i understand now. can u tell me what is wrong with this approach difference between $\sqrt[n]{n+1}$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}$ when n goes to infinity goes to 0 so their limits must be same.

Comment: @zorzpapadubi The point is that given $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$, in principle, we need to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$ holds.

Comment: ye i understand that.  u solution is 100% formally corect but my question is this: If i prove formally that limit of difference of $ \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n+1}- \sqrt[n]{n})\to 0 $, then their limits be same. is that correct

Comment: @zorzpapadubi Yes in that case since we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n+1}- \sqrt[n]{n})\to 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$$